# Apache Spark - Load data based on time

Tags: apache-spark

I have a use case where all data will be stored in XML files. 
Considering there is another application (running remotely) that places these files daily in S3 location (for example). However, all files are not uploaded to S3 location at one time. I may get some XML files on S3 location say at 9.00AM, few files at 1.00PM, few files at 6.00PM and rest of the files around 11.00PM.

The location for these files is the same and all files are separated by using date only.

My Spark job will run 4-5 times in a day and process these files. However, the job should not start its processing on previously processed files and should start on the newly added files.

Does Spark provide any way to identify the new files added to the location?

Thanks,

Avinash Deshmukh

Comment: Just to verify my assumptions are correct. If we are on Day 2 and files A, B, C, and D were uploaded on Day 1 and have already been processed, when file E is uploaded on Day 2, do you want this upload to trigger the Spark job? If file E is uploaded on Day 2 and then file F is uploaded also on Day 2, will the spark job run on files E and F or just F? Will the Spark job only ever run on the most recently uploaded single file?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, your assumption is correct. Day 1 files A,B,C and D were uploaded and already been processed on Day 1 (as data is partitioned by date). If file E is uploaded on Day 2 and Spark job is run around 6.00 AM suppose, the file E will get processed. On same day - Day2 - if file F is uploaded and run the Spark job again, it should process only file F and not file E.

Answer (score 1):

I worked on this kind of problem. We can do this by spark structured streaming if you don't have a problem of using streaming.

```
val df = spark.readStream
      .option("wholetext", true)
      .text("<S3 Bucket URI>\*.xml")
      .as[String]
// with the above line each xml file content will be as single string

val writeDF = df.writeStream
      .option("checkpointLocation", "<S3 Bucket URI for checkpointing>")
      .outputMode("append")
      .foreach(new CustomWriter)
      .queryName("xml-processing")
//Here we have to provide another S3 URI for checkpointing,
//If xml is processed by spark, then make commit as read with spark internal

val process = writeDF.start()
process.awaitTermination()
```

Need to Implement `CustomWriter` class by extending `ForeachWriter` class. 
So Here writer class will get the entire XML file content as String.

Comment: Hi Ravi, thanks for your response. However, my application is not a streaming job. Its a daily batch processing job which may run 3-4 times per day.